# AdmissionController holding back a Terminated Pod from getting completely removed

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks

I have an AdmissionController which is running successfully and prevents some pods from getting instantiated, checking on the prescribed conditions.

But the Pod gets stuck in Terminated Status and never goes away. I also have a process that monitors for stuck pods and cleans up. It tries to delete these Terminated Pods using deleteNamespacedPod. The Api call works fine, but the Pod lingers on without getting deleted. Is the AdmissionController denial a finalizer that is holding back the Pod from getting deleted ?

When I took down the Admission Controller, the clean up process was successfully able to delete the Pod.

Any insights or things I am missing in the AdmissionController ?

I appreciate any help/insights in this issue.

Thanks a lot,

-Sreeni

Comment: have you tried deleting the pod with `--grace-period 0 --force`?

Comment: Yes. That works. But I am more concerned about the Admission Controller holding the Pod from getting deleted.

Comment: Admission Controllers do not hold pods from being deleted. They are "admission" controllers. Their work is to intercept the object creation right after the authentication, but before the object creation.

Comment: Completely Agree. I am Trying to recreate the scenario again. it was unusually coincidental that these pods were not going away via the deleteNamespacedPod(coded with grace-period=0) API call from my clean up process and lingering on, but the same deletes worked as soon as I scaled down the admission-controller to 0. Thx!!

Comment: As @suren already stated admission controller should not block pod from being terminated. 

What plugins in admission controller have you enabled? 
Can you share some settings (what environment, is this happens for all pods or some specified one)

Comment: It was happening only with couple of pods which got denied by the Admission controller. I re-enabled the Admission controller and am monitoring. @ suren @Tomasz - a related question. The admission controller denied the pod request, but the replicaset keeps retrying. Is there a setting to limit the retries after certain number of attempts ? Thanks, Sreeni

Comment: I understand that you created your own Admission Controller. Without your setup it is hard to reproduce that situation. You could use your admission controller to oversees not only Pods but also ReplicaSet from being created (they don`t just apply for pod for any object).

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command against the terminated pod to delete it forcefully

```
kubectl patch pod <pod-name> -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

Comment: I can try that, but that involves manual command to be run, right ? I am trying to avoid that. I can try patching the Terminated Pod on my clean up process before attempting to delete.                                                                                                   
       But my concern is why is the AdmissionController holding the pod back. I am using normal AdmissionReview with AdmissionResponse with allowed =false..Any ideas ?